# wso2 api manager cloudfoundry

Tags: https, wso2, cloud-foundry, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to deploy wso2 api manager to cloudfoundry.

I have created a buildpack including the wso2 api manager. I am able to start the tomcat server and listen to http port. The https redirect doesn't work, an infinite redirect happens, when accessing https only urls like publisher. I tried changing the proxyport in `catalina-server.xml` (tried adding `X-Forward-Proto` in remote valve config). http urls work

Answer (score 0):

According to [This blog post](https://medium.com/@imesh/how-to-deploy-wso2-middleware-on-cloud-foundry-3b50291734e2#.j2rugeez2) this is a limitation, I assume.

> The existing CF architecture only supports exposing one port from a
>   container. Therefore a WSO2 server cluster can only expose one
>   transport from CF.